# Why this object destructuring in for-of loop doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, ecmascript-6

Basically the following code doesn't work and I don't understand why.
in the nested loop, I have a variable called "children" that is an array containing objects with fields called children (like in a DOM tree for instance). But it looks like their is a name conflict when I try to desctructure each element of the array. Since I'm using let they should have different scope (at least, the destructured variable should hide the "parent" one). It's likely that I'm wrong but I would like to understand why.

```js
let o = {
    children: [
     {children: [{}, {}, {}]},
     {children: [{}, {}, {}]}
    ]
};
for (let {children} of o.children) {
    console.log(children)
    for (let {children} of children) {
        console.log(children)
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have two levels of `children`, but you're trying to deconstruct three (`o.children`, `let {children}`, and again `let {children}`).

Comment: `let {children} of children` this will not work and will throw a ReferenceError, because `{children}` is used **before** declaring it, since it has the same name of `children`. Besides, the second for loop just can't work and destructuring won't work, because at that level you are already looping the empty objects.

Comment: Why do you even have two `for...of` loops? `let {children} of o.children` already takes care of the top level `children` key and the second level `children`

Answer (score 3):

By taking this statement,

```
for (let {children} of children)
```

you try to create a new local variable and take the same named variable as source for getting the elements for the new variable.

This does not work, because there is no distinction between both variables.

It would work, if you rename the target or source variable.

```js
let o = {
        children: [
            { children: [{ children: [{}, {}, {}] }, { children: [{}, {}, {}] }] },
            { children: [{ children: [{}, {}, {}] }, { children: [{}, {}, {}] }] },
        ]
    };

for (let { children } of o.children) {
    console.log(children)
    for (let { children: c } of children) { // rename here
        console.log(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I *think* the second `children` inside the `for` declaration is in the "Temporal Dead Zone", so trying to reference it throws a `ReferenceError`..? Though, what comes after the `of` should be a reference to something *in the outer scope*. I wonder if there's a reason why the spec says to attempt to reference the as-yet-undeclared first `children` if what comes after the `of` obviously can't be referencing it yet

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to get a property `children` from the wrong place. Remove the second `for` loop or rename your variable:

```js
let o = {
    children: [
     {children: [{}, {}, {}]},
     {children: [{}, {}, {}]}
    ]
};
for (let { children } of o.children) {
  console.log(children);
}
```

Or:

```js
let o = {
    children: [
     {children: [{children: "child"}, {children: "child"}, {children: "child"}]},
     {children: [{children: "child"}, {children: "child"}, {children: "child"}]}
    ]
};
for (let { children } of o.children) {
  console.log(children);
  for (let { children: childrenB } of children) {
    console.log(childrenB);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: _"You're attempting to get a property children from an empty object {}"_.Can you explain this. Where OP is trying to get property from **empty object**?

Comment: Whoops, my bad @MaheerAli

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the nested `for..of`. See the line

```
for (let {children} of children){...}
```

Here you are trying to get `children` property of `children` which doesnot make sense. Due to `let {children}` it creates a local variable `children` which is currently no initialized. Now the second `children` doesnot refer to parent array. But it refers to uninitialized variable in local scope.

The code in this case will throw a reference error.

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'children' before initialization"

Consider an object with name `children` and it property name is also `children`.You are doing same as below.

```js
let children = {children:'something'}
{
  let {children} = children;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you may add that it throws a **ReferenceError** :)